# undelete request

Tags: support, status-completed, undelete

The asker accepted my answer, and then deleted her question without cause.

[Details property in ListView not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582300/details-property-in-listview-not-displaying/15582376)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request granted!

> Post Undeleted by ThinkingStiff, Shadow Wizard, Mat

Comment: Great! Though, apparently I still don't get those 15 points back.

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunate. The OP had to unaccept to be able to delete, there's no reversing that (short of contacting the Stack Exchange staff, but I'm not sure they would grant such a request). I left a comment for the OP - hopefully they will come back and re-accept your answer. Plus now that the question has been "advertised" on meta, you might get a few upvotes that compensate :)

Comment: @j__m On the good side; you now have a couple up-votes on the answer (including one from me) which gives you more rep than the 15 you got from the accept - and prevents the OP from deleting the question again.